# Errors with UIPickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am getting these errors and i dont even know why

## 1: Type view controller does not conform with UIViewPickerDataSource

## 2: method pickerview(pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:) has different argument names from those required

Here is my code!
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIPickerView!

var timePickerData:[[Int]] = [[Int]]()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.timePicker.delegate = self
    self.timePicker.dataSource = self
    
    timePickerData = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51,52,  53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51,52,  53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return timePickerData.count
}

// The number of rows of data
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return timePickerData[component].count
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int?
{
    return timePickerData[component][row]
}
```

}

Comment: What's your XCode version?

Comment: i think its 8.1 GM. I just downloaded the latest one on app store.
I'm new to this btw. Trying to pick up swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using XCode 8, but your code uses old Swift 2.2 `UIPickerView` API. My suggestion for correction:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIPickerView!

var timePickerData:[[Int]] = [[Int]]()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.timePicker.delegate = self
    self.timePicker.dataSource = self

    timePickerData = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51,52,  53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51,52,  53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return timePickerData.count
}

// The number of rows of data
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return timePickerData[component].count
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
private func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> Int?
{
    return timePickerData[component][row]
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try as soon as i could get on my computer.
so, is my API old or something ? Anyway I can get the "better" one ?

Comment: @long New API declarations are packaged along with the XCode itself, so you'll get them for free as you install XCode 8. So I think that no additional actions required since you already seems to have an Xcode 8 or fresher.